# Bar graph with target values in each line in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

[image: Bar graph with target values in each line]

I am looking for a target bar line graph for each category in Power BI as shown in the picture (This graph was created in SAS VA).

X-axis is showing quarter
Y-axis is showing values of quarter results of 3 options (in a group e.g. yes, no and either)
Target lines showing region values of 3 options (in a group e.g. yes, no and either)